# CSS3 Animations and IE11 don't work in html file but on jsfiddle fine

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I'm trying to figure out why `css3` animations aren't working in my local website in **Internet Explorer (10)**. In any other browser everything is fine (Chrome, Firefox).
Read a lot about scoping issues in **ie** with media queries and so on. So I tried to reduce the source of errors by removing anything out of the html page except a `div` container and the `css` declarations which should apply the animation. On trying to find the issue I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjo3h0xk/) and was surprised that it was working there!?!.

So thinking about the differences I only found a `style` tag on example page  instead of linking to an external css file. But putting css into an external file was without success too.

Don't know else what I should look for.

Here's the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    @-webkit-keyframes scaleUpDown {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
    }

    @keyframes scaleUpDown {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            /*-ms-transform: scale(1);*/
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            /*-ms-transform: scale(1.5);*/
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
    }

    div.scaling {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        background-color: #00f;
        z-index: 1;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
        animation-duration: 30s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-name: scaleUpDown;
        animation-name: scaleUpDown;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternative;
        animation-direction: alternative;
        -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: bottom center 50%;
        transform-origin: bottom center 50%;
    }
</style>
<div class="scaling"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `transform` and `transform-origin` in IE9 need a vendor prefix, [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#animations) is not supported at all. Just remove the `x-ua` meta tag.

Comment: The property for animation-direction is alternate, not alternative.